Problem with the hinge mechanism of my folding bike (Smart Truck 300, made ~2016)
Updates after 3 months
Hello! Thank you all for being responsive. I don't know if anyone will read this thread now. But after 3 months of riding this bike I managed to open the mechanism. At first glance, there does not seem to be any breakage. The spring has become weak or the nuts at the bottom have come off.  Is there any way to fix it? The local service said they would not do anything, but this was at the stage when the mechanism could not be opened.



Smart Truck 300 bicycle, 2016. It seems to be made in China or Korea, it is impossible to find the manufacturer.
Problem:
-The folding mechanism clicks
-The handle of the mechanism has come loose
-The bicycle cannot be folded, but it is not 100% fixed
How the problem appeared:
The bicycle had not been folded for several years, we rode it once a year. It was in good working order. It became necessary to send the bicycle to another city, they tried to fold it, they lubricated the mechanism. They could not fold it completely, it bent a little and did not go further. They sent it to another city. They assembled it here and found that the handle of the mechanism does not hold (it moves very easily in the open and closed positions), the bicycle clicks at the fold point when you get on it, and when you press it, it bends a little in the folding mechanism.
It is scary to ride
What can be done?






could you provide pictures both from the other side and in (halfway) folded state? That might help

added new photos to the post. no photo of it folded, it doesn't fold, it can only bend it about 5 degrees.

I'm stumped on how to help. Any search result that has "smart bike 300" in it is 5 to 10 years old and is a dead link. Searching for some other bike that is similar to find documentation has turned up nothing. It's going to take someone with tools and aptitude to spend some time with it and then there is no guarantee it can be fixed. It might be time for a new bike.

Hi Anna, I am tryin to understand how the locking mechanism works on your bike. What is the big blue button on the other side of the of the bike opposite the hinge side?
This youtube link below, has a video of another folding bike with the lock on the same side as the hinge but notice that on the other side of the hinge there is a bolt adjustment.  If you watch this video at 2 minutes and 25 seconds into the video the instructor says that if the bolt adjustment is too tight you wont be able to open the hinge. I wonder if your bike has an adjustment bolt on the opposite side of the hinge.

Here is the youtube link.
https://youtu.be/XKpadZOTxTo?si=MadotBUumIuKHa5U

Now its open, I'd suggest lubricating all the moving parts.  That will help with both longevity and function.

My guess is that someone has stood on the bike while it was locked, which has slightly bend the bolt or mis-aligned the bosses that hold the bolt/pin.
Since things are now misaligned, there is binding which prevents the hinge from moving through 180 degrees.
Picture #3 shows a threaded hole for a grub screw, BUT I can also see the red of the lock through the hole.  That seems wrong, like something is missing.
You'll need to inspect closer, and I'd remove that grub screw then try to pull the pin and see if its subtly bent.  It could also just be dry-crusty lubricant jamming the works.
Good luck !

Thank you so much for your answers! We haven't figured out how to fix it yet. Decided to test ride it for a couple days (it doesn't show any bad signs while riding)
Last question, how realistic is it to take the frame from another bike (want to buy a used bike with a good frame) and rearrange all the parts? Speeds, bike handlebars, and others. Are there many parts that may not fit? (For example, seat tube diameter, etc.)? I'm a student and budget is pretty low, and this bike has a lot of good parts on it (brakes, shifters). have an interest in building a bike from scratch

@AnnaBeknazarova It is definitely possible to make one good bike from multiple parts donors.  It just takes time, and generally works better if the bikes have similar wheel sizes.  Though I have also put 8 speed parts from a 26" MTB onto a 20" folder - some creativity may be required.   You might like to join [chat] for a more free-form discussion over time.

good afternoon, yes, it is the same mechanism. a large button is needed to fold the bike (you need to lift the lever + hold the button). I did not add a photo in folded form, because I can not fold it (it is scary to use force). the problem is that it seems to be closed, but when driving in this area there are clicks, and manually you can bend the frame a little in this place towards the opening of the mechanism (by a couple of centimeters)
